# Task Management using Silverlight and SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight-5.0, signalr

I would like to develop a simple task management software with ASP.NET MVC (server side), Silverlight 5, JavaScript (client side - two different clients)

There are two types of users:

1. Team Lead
2. Team Member

They will have their own task list

There are more than one teams and notifications and updates should be sent to related team member.

Functionality:

1. Team lead will create a task and assigns to a team member.  As soon as team lead assigns task to a member, his task list should be updated in realtime.  Task should appear in team lead and team member task list.
2. When team member starts working he will update the status of task from "pending" to "working" and then "completed".  Task status in team lead's list should be updated in realtime when assignee updates the status.

Any help, reference application or sample is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is for ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) - please read the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Yes, this question is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you're in the early stages of development/still learning SignalR so I'll point you to some good resources to get yourself started.  Of course in addition to all the resources listed below there is plenty of information throughout StackOverflow to give you the basis of creating hubs/communicating with the server etc.

Info:

- http://signalr.net/
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Talks
- Twitter: @SignalR, @davidfowl, @DamianEdwards, @NTaylorMullen, @StephenHaltR

Source:

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Projects to take a peak at:

- Take a peak at JabbR: https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR
- GittR (in progress): https://github.com/DamianEdwards/GittR

Lastly, feel free to stop by the SignalR chat channel in JabbR if you run into any issues: http://jabbr.net/#/rooms/signalr

That should be plenty to get you started, hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have any similar sample/example applicatin?  I will definitely try to learn but a to the point example might help a lot.

Comment: See the Projects section of my response or download the SignalR source code.  Within the source code there is a set of sample projects

Comment: i am new on stackoverflow and also new to SignalR and web development in general.  next time i will be more specific. moderator: please close this question or delete it if you want.